# Multiple fixed elements only inside it's wrapping div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, scroll

I've been trying to make a fixed element only inside it's wrapping div, but can't get it to work even though I've tried all of the examples I've found here.

My site [can be seen here](http://www.kassett.no/kassett2/projects.html). (doesn't work with screens under 800px yet)

I need the project sidebar to stay fixed until the wrapper around it ends and a new section begins. [Here is an illustration of what I try to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gSnr.jpg)

I've been using the ScrollToFixed - plugin and tried out most of the examples I've found on stackoverflow. My basic structure look like this:

```
<section class="projects" id="nobelbopel">
    <div class="description" id="#nobelbopel-desc"></div>
    <div class="projectimages"></div>
</section>

<section class="projects" id="ujevnt">
    <div class="description" id"#ujevnt-desc"></div>
    <div class="projectimages"></div>
</section>
```

I want the .description to stop at the top of the browser top, but don't outside of it's wrapping div (.projects). The height of the wrapping div (.projects) is also varying, and I think thats my main problem..

I've tried using this code, but it only works partially:

```
$('#nobelbopel-desc').scrollToFixed( { 
marginTop: 154, 
limit: $('#ujevnt').offset().top 
- $('#nobelbopel-desc').height() - 154 } );

$('#ujevnt-desc').scrollToFixed( { 
marginTop: 154, 
limit: $('#bygdalarm').offset().top 
- $('#ujevnt-desc').height() } );
```

and this:

```
$('#nobelbopel-desc').scrollToFixed({
marginTop: 154,
limit: $('#ujevnt').offset().top - 154
});
```

As you can see from the code I want it 154 px from the top)
but I need a code that works whether the height of the wrapping div is 100 or 1000px, and preferably based on the basic class-structure than specific divs as it is now.

Comment: That'd be like the "Voting / Sharing / Title / Description" box on 9gag.com?

Comment: Yes! That is correct! :)